# F#: any way to use member functions as unbound functions?

Tags: f#, function, member-functions

Is there a way to extract member functions, and use them as F# functions? I'd like to be able to write the following:

```
mystring |> string.Split '\n' |> Array.filter (string.Length >> (=) 0 >> not)
```

The code above works if you [let]

```
let mystring = "a c\nb\n"
let stringSplit (y:char) (x:string) = x.Split(y)
let stringLength (x:string) = x.Length
mystring |> stringSplit '\n' |> Array.filter (stringLength >> (=) 0 >> not)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite similar to [a question I asked a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992992/f-higher-order-property-accessors) (but your wording is better). The consensus seems to be:

1. No.
2. Maybe the syntax `string#Split`, `"foo"#Split`, or just `#Split` (type-inferred) will be added in the future. But [Don Syme's proposal](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/3253.aspx) that Tomas linked to was from 2007, so I don't know how likely it is to happen--probably about as likely as a specific syntax for laziness, I'd guess.

Edit:

I guess `"foo"#Split` could also be written as `string#Split "foo"`. I guess it depends how flexibly you define the `#` syntax.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
(fun x -> x.Member ...)
```

for now.  For example

```
someString |> (fun s -> s.Split "\n") |> ...
```